# Python | int() function

Tags: python

I'm using Windows 10.

Python | int() function
int() function in Python and Python3 converts a number in given base to decimal. ... string : consists of 1's and 0's base : (integer value) base of the number. Returns : Returns an integer value, which is equivalent of binary string in the given base.

1.3.5: Read user input numbers and perform a calculation.

Read two numbers from user input. Then, print the sum of those numbers.
Hint -- Copy/paste the following code, then just type code where the questions marks are to finish the code.

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = ?
print(num1 + ?)**
```

This question ends up changing in this activity after I run the code. The questions starting with 1.3.5. is all I have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have just misread the prompt. It's just telling you to read 2 numbers from input. `input()` is a builtin that takes a `msg/question` param and prompts the user for some input. It doesn't return until it receives that input.

```
my_question = "Enter a number: " #not necessary
num1 = int(input(my_question))
num2 = int(input(my_question))
print(num1 + num2)
```

Comment: Without an example to show me how to work this problem I had no clue how to solve it. I am a quadriplegic who uses a SmartNav handicap application to type, so I thought it might be my handicap application that wouldn't allow me to work this out. The example you gave was all I needed to figure this out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not a problem!!